# Which Generic Types are allowed in the `Vec<T>` implementation of `ParallelExtend`

Tags: recursion, rust, traits, rayon

I am new to Rust and I am writing a recursive directory traversal program. This project is just an opportunity to learn Rust and parallelism with [Rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/). This question is a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74105347/parallel-recursion-fix/74105697?noredirect=1#comment130997753_74105697) question which @KevinReid helped out a lot with.

Below is my attempt to use [`partition_map()`](https://doc.servo.org/rayon/iter/unzip/fn.partition_map.html#) followed by the errors I am receiving.

```
use std::fs;
use std::path::PathBuf;
use rayon::iter::{Either, IntoParallelIterator, ParallelIterator};


#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    path: PathBuf,
    files: Vec<PathBuf>,
    folders: Vec<Box<Node>>,
}

impl Node {
    pub fn new(path: PathBuf) -> Self {
        Node {
            path: path,
            files: Vec::new(),
            folders: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
    
    pub fn burrow(&mut self) {
        let mut contents: Vec<PathBuf> = ls_dir(&self.path);

        let ret: (Vec<PathBuf>, Vec<Box<Node>>) = contents.into_par_iter().partition_map(|item| 
                                if item.is_file() {
                                    self.files.push(item);
                                    Either::Left(self.files)
                                } else {
                                    let mut new_folder = Node::new(item);
                                    new_folder.burrow();
                                    self.folders.push(Box::new(new_folder));
                                    Either::Right(self.folders)
                                });
        println!("{:?}", ret);      
    }
}

fn ls_dir(path: &PathBuf) -> Vec<PathBuf> {
    let mut contents: Vec<PathBuf> = Vec::new();
    let current_dir: fs::ReadDir = fs::read_dir(path).unwrap();

    for file in current_dir {
        contents.push(file.unwrap().path());
    }
    contents
}

fn main() {
    let root_path: &str = ".";
    let root: PathBuf = PathBuf::from(root_path);
    let contents: Vec<PathBuf> = ls_dir(&root);
    let mut node: Node = Node::new(root);
   
    node.burrow();
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Vec<PathBuf>: ParallelExtend<Vec<PathBuf>>` is not satisfied
    --> src/main.rs:31:76
     |
31   |         let ret: (Vec<PathBuf>, Vec<Box<Node>>) = contents.into_par_iter().partition_map(|item| 
     |                                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ParallelExtend<Vec<PathBuf>>` is not implemented for `Vec<PathBuf>`
     |
     = help: the following implementations were found:
               <Vec<T> as ParallelExtend<&'a T>>
               <Vec<T> as ParallelExtend<T>>
note: required by a bound in `partition_map`
    --> /home/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rayon-1.5.3/src/iter/mod.rs:2167:29
     |
2167 |         A: Default + Send + ParallelExtend<L>,
     |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `partition_map`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Vec<Box<Node>>: ParallelExtend<Vec<Box<Node>>>` is not satisfied
    --> src/main.rs:31:76
     |
31   |         let ret: (Vec<PathBuf>, Vec<Box<Node>>) = contents.into_par_iter().partition_map(|item| 
     |                                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ParallelExtend<Vec<Box<Node>>>` is not implemented for `Vec<Box<Node>>`
     |
     = help: the following implementations were found:
               <Vec<T> as ParallelExtend<&'a T>>
               <Vec<T> as ParallelExtend<T>>
note: required by a bound in `partition_map`
    --> /home/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rayon-1.5.3/src/iter/mod.rs:2168:29
     |
2168 |         B: Default + Send + ParallelExtend<R>,
     |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `partition_map`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `my-project` due to 2 previous errors
exit status 101
```

It appears that `ParallelExtend<T> for Vec<T>` is producing the error because of what `T` is, namely, `PathBuf` and `Box<Node>`. I have seen a smaller non-recursive example where `T` is `&str`, for example in which these errors are not present. So the question is if this is fixable and just not implemented correctly, or `PathBuf` and `Box<T>` inherently do not satisfy something that `ParallelExtend` requires.

To test if the type `T` was the issue I ran

```
pub fn burrow(&mut self) {
        let mut contents: Vec<PathBuf> = ls_dir(&self.path);

        let ret: (Vec<&str>, Vec<&str>) = contents.into_par_iter().partition_map(|item| 
                                if item.is_file() {
                                    self.files.push(item);
                                    Either::Left("test")
                                } else {
                                    let mut new_folder = Node::new(item);
                                    new_folder.burrow();
                                    self.folders.push(Box::new(new_folder));
                                    Either::Right("test")
                                });
        println!("{:?}", ret);      
    }
```

and received

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*self.files` as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure
  --> src/main.rs:33:37
   |
33 | ...                   self.files.push(item);
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable

error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*self.folders` as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure
  --> src/main.rs:38:37
   |
38 | ...                   self.folders.push(Box::new(new_folder));
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0596`.
error: could not compile `my-project` due to 2 previous errors
exit status 101
```

which is a totally different issue/concept. Needless to say, with the added recursive component, I am lost in the sauce.

Comment: The error you're seeing is because you should be yielding *a single element* in your `partition_map` closure, not a `Vec` of elements. `Vec<T>` implements `ParallelExtend<T>`, not `ParallelExtend<Vec<T>>`.

Comment: I've left an answer on your previous question since I think its lead you down the wrong path here. While my comment above addresses your error, I don't think simply answering that would help with your underlying problem.